# Перестала работать авторизация в корпоротивном портале при переходе корпоративной сети в новый домен

Tags: авторизация

В наследство досталась поддержка портала, понемногу поддерживал. А тут организацию перевели в новый домен.
То есть раньше, например, был домен DOM, а теперь DOM-DM. Пока сервер с порталом не мигрировали в новый домен, выкручивался и заводил всех под старой учеткой старого домена. Авторизация через кукисы. Сегодня мигрировали сервер с порталом в новый домен, и авторизация перестала работать. Используется Апач 2.2, в конфиге Апача исправил с DOM на DOM-TN. Где что еще искать, не знаю? Помогите советом, пожайлуста.

Comment: @dima136, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д. О чем говорят log-файлы, как вообще работал до этого механизм авторизации?

Comment: Поправил текст.

Answer (score 1):

Тут возможно 9000+ вариантов:

1. Ошибка в конфиге.
2. Имя домена пишется в cookies, то есть кука ставится на несуществующий уже домен.
3. ....
4. И т.д. и т.п.

Сделайте поиск по всему коду вашего портала - ищите DOM и меняйте его на DOM-DM.
Сделайте dump вашей БД и проведите такую же операцию в SQL (потом не забудьте накатить исправленный файл обратно в базу).

Answer (score 0):

Похоже на опечатку в конфиге или в вопросе.

Был домен DOM, а теперь DOM-DM.

Исправил с DOM на DOM-TN.

DOM-DM<>DOM-TN

Comment: нет опечатки, так и есть